# duplicate record trigger for 3 fields

Tags: trigger

I Have a requirement to prevent duplicate records based on the 3 fields like first name,Middle Name,Last Name, no new records are allowed as duplicate .

i tried in this way ..
created a new formula field to concatenate  this 3 fields ..
like Full name= first name+Middle Name+Last Name.

this is my trigger

```
trigger duprecord on Registration__c (Before Insert) {
 for(Registration__c r:trigger.new)
{
 list<Registration__c> reg=[select id,Name,Full_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Middle_Name__c from Registration__c  where full_name__c =:r.full_name__c];


if(reg.size()>0)
{
r.addError('Same Records are Not Allowed');
}
}
}
```

please suggest is there any alternate way.

Thanks In Advance
Bhasakr

Comment: If you don't specify what is not working, we can't really help. Also, what alternatives did you already try? And lastly: please format your code correctly.

Comment: Here the problem is we are wasting memory like adding one more field..a formula field is used it is wasting memory ,its not required for that object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have SOQL inside for loop which is not best practice, we never add SOQL inside any loop.

```
set<String> setName =new set<String>(); //get existing records data
set<String> setFullName = set<String>(); //Name retention to throw error.
//get existing records data.    
for(Registration__c r:trigger.new)
{

 setName.add(r.full_name__c);

}

for(Registration__c reg=[select id,Name,Full_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Middle_Name__c from Registration__c  where full_name__c in :setName])
{
    setFullName.add(reg.Full_Name__c);
}

 //iterate over records and throw error
for(Registration__c r:trigger.new)
{

    if(setFullName.contains(r.full_name__c))
    {
        r.addError('Same Records are Not Allowed');
    }


}
```